# Is it possible to use variable in Datatable query?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have to query a datatable based on some condition.

Dim rows As DataRow() = dtPeriodFrom.Select("Value = 9")

I want to filter by value which is variable, is it possible to use variable in this select query?

Comment: If my interpretation of you're poorly-explained issue is correct then you're ignoring the blatantly obvious. The `Select` method requires a `String` but there's nothing to stop you constructing that `String` from whatever parts you want to use. How do you usually construct a `String` from parts? Do that here, e.g. `Dim rows = dtPeriodFrom.Select($"Value = {value}")`.

Comment: If you want to filter, use a filter: `[DataTable].DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Value = {Variable}"`. If you have a Column named `Value`, that is. But you may have a variable which has a value of `9` instead. So `[DataTable].DefaultView.RowFilter = $"[Field Name] = {Variable}"`

Comment: @Jimi, it depends how the results will be used. If the `DataTable` is bound to the UI then your code will affect what gets displayed. That may or may not be what is required. It might be that all records should be displayed in the UI but a subset need to be processed in code. Either way though, the filter expressions for the `Select` method and the `RowFilter` property work exactly the same way and so the same principles apply to both.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, this entirely depends on what should *happen*: `Select()` returns a collection of DataRows, while `RowFilter` applies the filter to the current DataView, it doesn't create new objects. A new sub-set and a filter are not the same thing. As you mentioned, the latter will affect the current view. The OP should clarify the real intention, what this code is used for, to have a more *focused* solution.

Comment: @Jimi, *"A new sub-set and a filter are not the same thing"*. That's getting into semantics. Would you say that a `WHERE` clause in a database query is not a filter? The parameter in the `Select` method is even named `filterExpression`, so I think that it's safe to say that Microsoft think it's a filter. If you were to create a new `DataView` and set the `RowFilter` on that, rather than using the `DefaultView`, would that not be a filter because you created a new object?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sure, the *not the same thing* is related to the result: one returns new objects, the other applies the filter internally, no new objects are created and the filter can be removed at any time or seamlessly replaced with another. It depends on the use-case, which, IMO, should be clarified.

Comment: @Jimi, *"one returns new objects"*. I think that you may be under a misconception there. `Select` returns an array of `DataRow` objects but none of those rows is newly created. They are the very same objects that are in the `Rows` collection of the `DataTable`. `myDataTable.Select("MyColumn = 'text')` would produce the same result as `myDataTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("MyColumn") = "text").ToArray()`.

Comment: @mcilhinney Yes, the new objects are the Arrays returned by `Select()`. Of course these objects contain references to existing DataRows, but you have new objects in hand and you have to do something with them. The questions is: what are you going to do with these objects? Do you really need them or you actually want to apply a filter to the current view? What is the purpose? (I'm not asking you, clearly :). I think the actual use-case is important (for the OP and future readers).

Comment: @jmcilhinney ...It also takes more time: the DataTable has to parse the whole binary tree, verify whether there's already a filter applied, create a `List<DataRow>`, then copy the resulting List to a new Array of DataRows.

Comment: @Jimi, I see what you're saying, although I disagree a bit with some of the terminology and motivation. Regardless, the better option is certainly going to be dependent on the requirements. That said, I don't think it really does need to be stated. The OP asked how to incorporate a variable into a filter expression and that won't change whichever option is used. In fact, it doesn't even have anything specifically to do with filter expressions as it's straight `String` construction, which is the same regardless of what the text represents.